# Plotly R: Interaction between subplot legend and highlight select

Tags: r, plotly

I am trying to get another plot to react to both legend (select/deselect levels of a factor) and drag select. In the following toy example drag select works as intended: the violin and boxplot are re-rendered to depict the points that are selected using the mouse. The legend works for the scatterplot, but not for the boxplot and violin that don't seem to share the legend. I read many posts about shared legend, but nothing worked for subplots of different types.

Even more surprisingly, when deplying to plotly cloud, [the plot](https://plot.ly/~ClaudiuPapasteri/3/#/) also loses it's drag select feature (altough I don't need the plotly cloud, I thought I should mention this).

Just to be clear, I'd like the boxplot and violin to be re-rendered based both on selecting on legend and drag-select on scatterplot. As these features theoretically work, the legend should provide the full data or subsets based on levels of the factor used for legend from which the drag selection could be carried out afterwards.

```
library(plotly)

d <- mtcars
d$cyl <- as.factor(d$cyl)
d <- highlight_key(mtcars)

sp <- plot_ly(d, x = ~mpg, y = ~disp, 
              color = ~factor(cyl), colors = c("red", "green", "blue"),
              legendgroup = ~factor(cyl), showlegend = T) %>%
add_markers()

box <- 
  plot_ly(d, y = ~disp, 
          color = I("black"), 
          legendgroup = ~factor(cyl), showlegend = F) %>% 
  add_boxplot(name = " ")

violin <- 
  plot_ly(d, y = ~disp, 
          color = I("black"), 
          legendgroup = ~factor(cyl), showlegend = F) %>%
  add_trace(type = "violin", name = " ")

p <- 
  subplot(sp, box, violin, shareY = TRUE, titleX = TRUE, titleY = TRUE) %>%
  layout(
      dragmode = "select",
      barmode = "overlay", 
      title = "Click and drag scatterplot",
      showlegend = TRUE
    ) %>%
  highlight(on = "plotly_selected", off = "plotly_deselect")

p
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I am not seeing the possibility of doing so (in my knowledge and with a conventional method) but this is an interesting question and worth more attention.